# Get ID based on cell contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the id of a row based on the contents of a cell.

```
$("tr td:contains(+data.id+)").parent().attr('id'));
```

data.id is a response from json, if I console log `data.id` it has a value. If I use this code in chrome console and manually enter the `data.id` such as ..

```
alert($("tr td:contains(1717)").parent().attr('id')));
```

I get the correct response but at runtime the result is undefined. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate the strings together:

```
$("tr td:contains(" + data.id + ")").parent().attr('id'));
```

`"tr td:contains(+data.id+)"` is literally just that, javascript won't automatically find the `+` and replace the `data.id`.